# Two JCheckbox sources?

Tags: java, swing, listener, actionlistener

I'm writing a small body weight program for my assignment. I have 2 JRadioButton for gender, and five JRadioButtons for the heightt categories. I added an ActionListener for each of these buttons.
In the actionPerformed function, how can I put an an if() condition that lets me decide on the ideal weight based on both the gender and the height?

```
if(e.getSource() == genderM && e.getSource() == h60 )
```

doesn't seem to be working.

The problem specifically states that it should be done without a submit button.

This is the code im working with:

```
public class IdealWeight extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JLabel lblHeight;
JLabel lblGender;
JLabel lblIdeal;
JRadioButton genderM;
JRadioButton genderF;
JRadioButton h60;
JRadioButton h64;
JRadioButton h68;
JRadioButton h72;
JRadioButton h76;
JTextField txtIdealWeight;

public IdealWeight(){
    super("Ideal Wight");
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
    lblGender = new JLabel("Your gender: ");
    lblHeight = new JLabel("Your height: ");
    lblIdeal = new JLabel("Your ideal weight: ");
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
    ButtonGroup genderGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup weightGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    genderM = new JRadioButton("Male: ");
    genderM.addActionListener(this);
    genderF = new JRadioButton("Female: ");
    genderF.addActionListener(this);
    h60 = new JRadioButton("60 to 64 inches");
    h60.addActionListener(this);
    h64  = new JRadioButton("64 to 68 inches");
    h64.addActionListener(this);
    h68  = new JRadioButton("68 to 72 inches");
    h68.addActionListener(this);
    h72  = new JRadioButton("72 to 76 inches");
    h72.addActionListener(this);
    h76  = new JRadioButton("76 to 80 inches");
    h76.addActionListener(this);
    txtIdealWeight = new JTextField();
    txtIdealWeight.setEditable(false);
    txtIdealWeight.setColumns(5);

    genderGroup.add(genderM);
    genderGroup.add(genderF);
    weightGroup.add(h60);
    weightGroup.add(h64);
    weightGroup.add(h68);
    weightGroup.add(h72);
    weightGroup.add(h76);
    p1.add(lblGender);
    p1.add(genderM);
    p1.add(genderF);

    p2.add(lblHeight);
    p2.add(h60);
    p2.add(h64);
    p2.add(h68);
    p2.add(h72);
    p2.add(h76);

    p3.add(lblIdeal);
    p3.add(txtIdealWeight);


    this.add(p1);
    this.add(p2);
    this.add(p3);

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));


}
```

Comment: Each time one of the controls triggers an action event, collect all the information you need which is indecent of the gender, then check which gender is selected and make the required calculations based on the previously collected information, these way you reduce the overhead of replicated code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

```
e.getSource() == genderM && e.getSource() == h60
```

Can never return true because the source is either genderM or h60. Perhaps you meant logical OR.

```
e.getSource() == genderM || e.getSource() == h60
```

As an alternative, I'd ignore the source of the event, and use the state of the components instead..

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (genderM.isSelected() && h60.isSelected()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: that was a typo. It's supposed to be h60, which is the name of the JRadioButton

Comment: Personally, the actionCommand property would be more suitable, as it won't rely on the text which is displayed to the user, which could make it easier to manage - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer This was all based on a misunderstanding caused by typo in original problem, answer updated.

Comment: It's just a personal thing,  prefer to work with the `actionCommand` property then things like the text or source

Answer (score 3):

Since the user needs to enter information in all fields before it can be accurately processed, I'd not use ActionListeners on your JCheckBoxes or JRadioButtons, but rather have a single JButton, say called submitButton and then extract the data from your GUI within its ActionListener.

You can get the selected item from each of the ButtonGroup objects that you're using, since it will return the ButtonModel of the JRadioButton selected, or null if nothing has been selected.

If you need more help -- please ask and also edit your question to show us more pertinent code.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> The problem specifically states that it should be done without a submit button

This is key information that should be part of your original question.

Then use one single ActionListener, and **don't worry about the source**. Instead in the ActionListener, either query all the JRadioButtons as to their state, and then act on it, or get the models out of your ButtonGroups and do the same.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoButtonGroups extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] LABELS_1 = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
   public static final String[] LABELS_2 = {"Fubar", "Snafu", "DILLIGAF"};
   private ButtonGroup buttonGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
   private ButtonGroup buttonGroup2 = new ButtonGroup();

   public TwoButtonGroups() {
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

      MyActionListener myActionListener = new MyActionListener();
      for (String label1 : LABELS_1) {
         JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(label1);
         radioButton.setActionCommand(label1);
         radioButton.addActionListener(myActionListener);
         buttonGroup1.add(radioButton);
         panel1.add(radioButton);
      }
      for (String label2 : LABELS_2) {
         JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(label2);
         radioButton.setActionCommand(label2);
         radioButton.addActionListener(myActionListener);
         buttonGroup2.add(radioButton);
         panel2.add(radioButton);
      }

      add(panel1);
      add(panel2);
   }

   private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         ButtonModel model1 = buttonGroup1.getSelection();
         ButtonModel model2 = buttonGroup2.getSelection();
         if (model1 == null || model2 == null) {
            return;  // not selected
         }

         System.out.printf("Selections: %s and %s%n", model1.getActionCommand(), model2.getActionCommand() );
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TwoButtonGroups mainPanel = new TwoButtonGroups();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TwoButtonGroups");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem specifically states that it should be done without a submit button. Also I added the code

Comment: Submit buttons are generally (in most cases) bad design. Why forcing the user to hit a button, if there is no real reason for it (means: if you already know when the input is completed)

Comment: @joe11093: see edit to answer for example using ButtonGroups and ButtonModels.

Comment: I ended up going with @adam 's answer. Thanks for your answer though. I will read up on ActionCommands as soon as possible.